# Perform math on one-line ruby script gsub regex captures

Tags: ruby, regex, shell

I'm trying to fix a subtitles (.srt) text file that has some incorrect data with a one-line ruby script. The file looks like this:

```
53
00:03:52,835 --> 00:03:54,835
Boss?... BOSS?!

54
00:03:54,845 --> 00:03:56,990


55
00:0 --> 00:03:58,490
Go!

I want the 55 stanza to look like this:

55
00:03:56,490 --> 00:03:58,490
Go!
```

Where the first time stamp is taken from the second but with 2 seconds subtracted.

Here is my attempt, which is not working:

```
ruby -pi.bak -e 'gsub(/(\d{2}):(\d) --> (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d{3})/, "#{$3}:#{$4}:#{$5},#{$6} --> #{$3}:#{$4}:#{$5.to_i - 2},#{$6}")' *.srt
```

**EDIT**

So, as pointed out by the responders, ruby 1.9.2 does not support access of regex captures via the $1, $2, etc. syntax.

The fix I ended up going with was switching back to ruby 1.8.x, and using gsub with a block as @mu suggested, and used the Time.utc / strftime magic suggested by @jonas.

Here is the final solution (on my system /usr/bin/ruby is 1.8.6):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -pi.bak -e 'gsub(/(\d{2}):(\d) --> (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d{3})/) {"#{(Time.utc(1970,1,1, $3,$4,$5) - 2).strftime("%H:%M:%S")},#{$6} --> #{$3}:#{$4}:#{$5},#{$6}"}' *.srt
```

I am now watching my movie with correctly formatted subtitles. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Why do you have to do this in one line?

Comment: I guess you'll have to parse the second time as some kind of time class. Otherwise `00:04:00` will get seriously wrong with your proposed solution.

Comment: “[Now you have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)” You should probably be using more than a single regular expression to do this.

Comment: @Jonas: 00:04:00 will be ignored by the `gsub` as it won't match, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @Wilbur: This looks like a perfectly sensible using a regex to me, I don't see any "when all I have is a hammer" confusion here.

Comment: The badness that you're trying to fix is just the "00:0" line, right?

Comment: @mu What I meant was that if it's `00:0 --> 00:04:00,490` subtracting 2 from the last `00` will get him in trouble.

Comment: @Jonas: Okay, that makes sense then, I thought you meant `/^00:04:00/`.

Comment: @mu @igagen Ah, my apologies. I should have read the regex and question more carefully.

Comment: @Jonas it doesn't have to be a one-liner, and now I'm thinking maybe I should just write a 4 or 5 line script instead and save the hassle... Just figured if the perl guys can do everything in one-line, why can't we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it but you want to use the [block form of `gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) rather than the two argument form and I think you have your subtraction on the wrong side of `--->`:

```
ruby -pi.bak -e '$_.gsub(/(\d{2}):(\d) --> (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d{3})/) { "#{$3}:#{$4}:#{$5.to_i - 2},#{$6} --> #{$3}:#{$4}:#{$5},#{$6}" }' *.srt
```

Ruby 1.8 doesn't need the `$_` with the block form of `gsub` but 1.9 does. The global `$1`, `$2`, ... aren't what you think they are [except in block form of `gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub):

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched text. [...] However, within `replacement` the special match variables, such as `&$`, will not refer to the current match.
>
> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $’ will be set appropriately.

Jonas Elfström is right in the comments about subtracting 2 from the seconds in "00:04:00" making a mess. So you might want to use one of the time classes to handle your subtraction. Something like this:

```
(Time.utc(1970,1,1, $3,$4,$5) - 2).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

in place of your `#{$3}:#{$4}:#{$5.to_i - 2},#{$6}` should do the trick. [`Time.utc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-c-utc) wants to work with a full date-time rather than just a time so using the Unix epoch (1970-01-01) is a bit of a hack to get around that. Of course, if you try to subtract 2s from 00:00:00 you'll run into some problems.

Comment: For some reason when I use the block form of gsub (per your snippet), it is just generating a bunch of Enumerable objects and calling to_s on those. The output looks like this:  #<Enumerator:0x0b5aa4>#<Enumerator:0x0b5a40>#<Enumerator:0x0b59f0>#<Enumerator:0x0b59a0>#<Enumerator:0x0b5950>#<Enumerator:0x0b5900>#<Enumerator:0x0b58b0>#<Enumerator:0x0b5860>

Comment: @igagen: I've added an update for 1.9, you just need to explicitly say `$_.gsub` with the block form, 1.8 works without the `$_`.

Comment: @rogerdpack: Where would `$1` be used?

Comment: @rogerdpack: Because `$2` and friends are only valid in the block as the documentation states.